# Transfer really large files using WebClient

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient

My requirement is to transfer a zip file of size 400MB or more; The following code works for at least 40MB; But for more I would have to change `byte[] bytes = new byte[50000000];` to `byte[] bytes = new byte[400000000];` and maxRequestLength to `maxRequestLength="409600"`;

The problem is `byte[] bytes = new byte[100000000];` returns an error regarding insufficient space. So how can I transfer large files using WebClient??

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:57596/UploadImages.ashx");
ub.Query = "ImageName=" + "DataSet" + DataSetId + ".zip";
client.OpenWriteCompleted += (InputStream, eArguments) =>
{

    try
    {
        using (Stream output = eArguments.Result)
        {

            output.Write(ImagesAux, 0, (int)ImagesAux.Length);
            //numeroimagem++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //throw;
    }

};
client.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
```

in  UploadImages.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

    string ImageName = context.Request.QueryString["ImageName"];
    string UploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/ServerImages/");

    using (FileStream stream = File.Create(UploadPath + ImageName))
    {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[50000000]; // 
        int bytesToRead = 0;

        while ((bytesToRead =
        context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {

            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
            stream.Close();

        }

    }

}
```

in Web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="40960"/>
```

Comment: bytes[500000] is only the buffer size which I would keep lower, don't close the stream at each write just at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should never load everything in memory then write all back to disk, but instead you should load pieces and write them to disk while you are reading them.
When you've done reading you close the stream you are writing to.
Otherwise as soon as you reach sizes as GB you can get an OutOfMemory really quick.

So I would change the writing bytes to disk from this:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(UploadPath + ImageName))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[50000000]; // 
    int bytesToRead = 0;
    while ((bytesToRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

to this:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(UploadPath + ImageName))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    long totalBytes = context.Request.InputStream.Length;
    long bytesRead = 0;
    int bytesToRead = bytes.Length;

    if (totalBytes - bytesRead < bytes.Length)
        bytesToRead = (int)(totalBytes - bytesRead);
    bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];

    while ((bytesToRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, bytesRead, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, bytesRead, bytes.Length);

        bytesRead += bytes.Length;
        if (totalBytes - bytesRead < bytes.Length)
            bytesToRead = (int)(totalBytes - bytesRead);
        bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];

    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

1024 would be the buffer size.